# Binding textbox text to a xml file in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF programming. Please help me here.

I want the data entered in textboxes to be updated in the xml file. Here is my code.

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="credential_data" Source="Credentials.xml" XPath="/Credentials/MB"/>
</Window.Resources>


     <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource credential_data}}">                            
              <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox5" Width="188" Text="{Binding XPath=Hostname, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
              <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox6" Width="188" Text="{Binding XPath=Port, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is Credentials.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Credentials>
    <MB>
        <Hostname>10.111.123.234</Hostname>
        <Port>8080</Port>
    </MB>
</Credentials>
```

What is happening now is that any updates in the xml file gets reflected in the textboxes but any changes in textbox.text does not update the xml file.

where am I going wrong?? :(

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the xml **file** is not changed immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not giving you a full example, but this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26875/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding) already has a tutorial project that does **exactly** what you want